# What does @() in front of a matrix?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I want to know what is the following operation in MATLAB:

```
r_BF_inB = @(alpha,beta,gamma)[...
    -sin(beta + gamma) - sin(beta);...
  sin(alpha)*(cos(beta + gamma) + cos(beta) + 1) + 1;...
  -cos(alpha)*(cos(beta + gamma) + cos(beta) + 1)];
```

What does @() mean?

THanks in advance

Comment: it means `r_BF_inB` is a function handler with variables `alpha`, `beta` and `gamma`

Comment: See MATLAB [function handle](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/function_handle.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is syntax for anonymous functions. You can refer to following link:
http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html

Answer (score 2):

`@` is used to declare ["Function Handles"](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/function_handle.html).

The format is like: `handle = @(arglist)anonymous_function`
where an [anonymous function](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html) is what is executed by calling said handle.

Comment: Sorry, I have to (temporarily) downvote. There is no such thing as a matrix of function handles. From the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/function_handle.html): "_you cannot construct a function_handle array.  The reason is that the parenthesis notation for values of this class is used to call a function, not to index an array.To achieve the effect of an array of function handles, use cells, e.g., write `A = {@sin, @cos}` rather than `A = [@sin, @cos]`_." The matrix in the OP means that the function returns an array of values.